# Why isn't execution of system command working in VBA macro?

Tags: vba, shell

I have a working command that unzips zip file when passed to command line. However, when I try to execute this command from VBA macro, it isn't doing anything.
VBA:

```
Sub Test()
Shell("powershell.exe -command Expand-Archive -Force C:\Test\test.zip C:\Test\")
End Sub
```

I've also tried:

```
Sub Test()
Call Shell("powershell.exe -command Expand-Archive -Force C:\Test\test.zip C:\Test\", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Thank you for your suggestions ;)

Comment: It probably doesn't know where `powershell.exe` is. Include the full path to it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it

Comment: So I added a path: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe but still not working...

Answer (score 1):

I made it work:

```
Sub Test()
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Run("powershell.exe -command Expand-Archive -Force C:\Test\test.zip C:\Test\")
End Sub()
```

Comment: To get rid of popup add ```,0``` behind the command

Answer (score 0):

Please, try it in this way:

```
Sub TestUnzip()
    Shell "powershell.exe Expand-Archive -Force C:\Test\test.zip C:\Test\" 
End Sub
```

Of course, a "test.zip" file must exist in "C:\Test" folder...

If the full name will contain spaces, it must be placed between quotes:

```
'C:\My Test\test.zip'
'C:\Test\first test.zip'
```